# Is there a way to take lock on a collection in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, linkedhashset

I have a requirement where I am using a LinkedHashSet and converting it to json(I need unique elements and need to maintain order hence using LinkedHashSet). I need to take a lock on this collection so that when I am converting it to json, no other process/thread should be able to modify it. basically I want to avoid concurrent modification exception on the collection.

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        synchronized(linkedHashSet){
            val jsonString = Gson().toJson(linkedHashSet)
            sharedPreferences?.edit()?.putString("DataList", jsonString)?.apply()
        }
    }
```

I tried this but doesn't seem to work as i am still getting concurrent modification exception. Any other way?

Comment: What does `Couroutine.Dispatcher(IO){` do? It doesn't look like a standard coroutines code, so either you use some custom utils or this is invalid code. Generally, `synchronized()` won't work properly with coroutines. You can use e.g. [Mutex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.sync/-mutex/), but it depends on what do you do with the IO dispatcher here.

Comment: @broot I modified the code corrected it. I am using couroutines to convert my collection to json on a background thread. Will using Mutex take lock on linkedHashSet?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you use? I ask because I believe this should not generate concurrent modification exception and before the edit your code was the opposite: you used `launch()` inside `synchronized()` (which in fact would generate CME).

Comment: @broot Yes, this one is the correct code i use. But i am getting CME.

Comment: Could you share the code where you modify the list?

Comment: Actually its modified at multiple places by calling normal add, remove, addAll and removeAll based on if data needs to be added or removed from set. Once set is modified I am saving it to preference by converting to json. But it looks toJson method is using an iterator internally to iterate through the list and somehow data is getting modified in list throwing CME.

Comment: You need to synchronize all places where you modify it.

Comment: yeah but its very comursome.

Comment: Then wrap it in a class that internally locks and passes through modifications and iterations.

Comment: Well in that case how can I lock iterator and forEach() ?

Comment: You can't.  Really, you will just have to synchronize all call sites.